# Tapping to cancel a Download

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I want to do the following:

1)DownLoad a series of files whose URLs are stored in an NSMutableArray.

2)During the download process a MBProgressHUD shows the download status.

3)At any point of download I want to cancel the download, when the user touches the screen.

```
-(void)singleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
NSLog(@"%@",@"tapped");
self.downLoadHud.detailsLabelText=@"";
self.downLoadHud.labelText=[SAGlobal stringForValue:@"CANCELLINGDOWNLOAD"];
SharedAppDelegatee.downLoadCancelFlag=YES;

}

-(void) startFileDownLoadingWithHUD
{

self.downLoadHud=[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:[SharedAppDelegatee window] animated:YES];
self.downLoadHud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
UITapGestureRecognizer *HUDSingleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTap:)];
[self.downLoadHud addGestureRecognizer:HUDSingleTap];
self.downLoadHud.labelText = @"Initialising..";
self.downLoadHud.detailsLabelText =@"";
[self.downLoadHud setColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, ^(void)
{

    [self startAllFilesInArrayDownload];
    //downloadcancelled or downloadfinished
    while (!(SharedAppDelegatee.downLoadCancelFlag)||(SharedAppDelegatee.SAdownloadMode==0)) {

         self.downLoadHud.labelText =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloading..[%d/%d]",self.self.downloadErrorCount+self.downloadSuccessCount,[filesToDownLoad count]];
          self.downLoadHud.detailsLabelText =[SAGlobal stringForValue:@"TAPTOCANCEL"];
        //NSLog(@"DOWNLOADING------+");
    }
    ////////////////////////////////
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.downLoadHud hide:YES];
        //downLoadHud
    });
});
```

}

The download is done with

```
for (downDict in filesToDownLoad)
{
    //[adm downloadURL:[downDict objectForKey:@"url"]  destPath:[downDict objectForKey:@"toFile"]];
    NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[downDict objectForKey:@"url"]];
    [self.downloadManager addDownloadWithFilename:[downDict objectForKey:@"toFile"] URL:aUrl];
    //[urlStringsArray addObject:[downDict objectForKey:@"url"]];
}
```

The "downloadManager" is an object of class "DownloadManager" which is obtained
https://github.com/robertmryan/download-manager

I could succesively download all files. I am NOT able to cancel the download in the middle of download. When the user taps the button, it waits a long time, and after some time, the  "singleTap" method is called.
The number of files downloaded and failed are CORRECTLY shown. What is wrong with my code?. Can any one suggest me a better example or way to handle "Showing a busy hud + downloading+ tap to cancel feature similar as shown below.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

While I am certain that this is a great utility and a lot of work went into it I was immediately concerned when i saw that the repo was two years old.
These types of things are a great help and i can't begin to express my appreciation for the authors and their generosity in sharing so much hard work.  Unfortunately, if they are not maintained then they can become difficult for the user to update.

Apple has more recently introduced new functionality with NSURLSession.

This is pretty easy to use and is much more powerful than NSURLConnection.

It specifically includes the ability to pause, resume and cancel network downloads.